# Is it possible to change data by second endorsing peer after signed by first endorsing peer?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

If it is possible then how ?
Please suggest me.
I am trying to start my project which is in designing phase right now

Comment: I would suggest you start by reading the Key Concepts in the Fabric Documentation, then working through some of the tutorials.  Good luck with the project :)
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/key_concepts.html
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials.html

Answer (score 2):

Please try to provide further information about what are you trying to do.

But the short answer is No.

The signature of the first is generated using the Read and Write Set data.
If the second endorser change this data the signature of the first one will not match anymore.
Committing Peers verifies all signature before commit, so your transaction will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

According to the hyperledger fabric transactions flow, the client submits the transaction to an endorser for endorsement. Then the endorser executes the transaction and returns the read and write sets by signing with its keys, to the client.
 
So in the flow, the data by an endorsing peer does not go through another endorser to the client, the data is directly provided to the requesting client. In short an endorser can not modify the data provided by another endorser to the client. 
For further reference you can refer to the official documentation - [Reference](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/txflow.html)